# How to perform addition from multiple files using executor service and gives final output

Tags: java, executorservice

Below is the piece of code which I have tried. Each file is having an integer and I want to add all the integer and display the output

```
@Override
public void run() {
    BlockingQueue<Integer> d;
    try {
        d = readFile(file);
        //System.out.println("adding the integers ..."+d.take());
        i = (int) d.take();
        System.out.println("i = "+i);
        sum = sum + i;

        //System.out.println("ai = "+ai.incrementAndGet());
        System.out.println("sum = "+sum );
     } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     // ProcessedData p = d.process();
     // writeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), "C:/test");
}

private BlockingQueue<Integer> readFile(File file2) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file2);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(file2));
    int content = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    System.out.println("content = "+content);
    System.out.println("reading and writing to blocking queue...");
    blockingQueue.put(content);
    return blockingQueue;
}
```

Comment: well from a first look, it seems you confused the `BlockingQueue`'s usage as `sum` variable will never be returned properly, check this [simple example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-blocking-queue) and this more [advanced example](https://dzone.com/articles/java-blocking-queue-continuous-monitoring), which might be more relevant to your use case, and handle it in terms of sequential events.

Comment: I donot understand why I can't use blockingqueue in executorserivce and add  ? If some one can help would be really appreciated !!

Comment: nope i am not saying you cant, i am saying you have a bit over-complexed the process. Also you are using 2 `FileReader` instances without actual usage. From your example the `sum` reference looks like a private thread variable, which means no one has access to it!?! so are you going just to print it ? or should the actual blocked thread count all the values from queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for the problem  -

When I am adding all the integers from the queue using atomic integer, each thread has a different copy of the atomic variable.

So, Every time when addAndGet method is used it is updated with the value from the blocking queue.

I have seggregated and created a singleton class which returns me the same atomic integer object for every thread when requested.

Below is the snippet of code and this solved my problem -

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class AtomicState {

```
private static final AtomicState as = new AtomicState();

public AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();

private AtomicState() {

}

public AtomicInteger getAtomicIntegerObj() {
    return ai;
}


public static AtomicState getAtomicState() {
    return as;
}
```

}